# Why is this django registration mechanism not working for my custom user model?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin, python-3.7

I was working on a project where I was implementing a custom user model using django and registration,login for the same. But unfortunately, I guess the registration mechanism doesn't work correctly. How do I know that is, in Admin panel, it shows the new user where while trying to login with the new user, I get "Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive." . I've spent around 2 days googling,stackoverflowing. But none of them has solved my problem.

***My Code***

**Models.py:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager

class CustomAccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_superuser(self, email, username, password, **other_fields):
        other_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
        other_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)
        if other_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must be assigned to is_staff=True.')
        if other_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must be assigned to is_superuser=True.')
        
        return self.create_user(email, username, password, **other_fields)

    def create_user(self, email, username, password, **other_fields):

        if not email:
            raise ValueError(_('You must provide an email address'))

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, username=username, **other_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

class UserModel(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    PROFILE_PIC_CHOICES = (
        ('Male1.svg', 'Male1'),
        ('Male2.svg', 'Male2'),
        ('Male3.svg', 'Male3'),
        ('Female1.svg', 'Female1'),
        ('Female2.svg', 'Female2'),
        ('Female3.svg', 'Female3'),
        ('DefaultImage.jpg','Default Image'),
    )
    profile_pic = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=PROFILE_PIC_CHOICES, default="DefaultImage.jpg")
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    about = models.TextField(_('about'), max_length=500, blank=True)
    tags = models.CharField(max_length=100000, blank=True, null=True)
    insta = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    fb = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    linkedin = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    twitter = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('MALE', 'Male'),
        ('FEMALE', 'Female'),
        ('OTHERS', 'Others'),
        ('RATHER NOT SAY', 'Rather not say'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=14, choices=GENDER_CHOICES, default='RATHER NOT SAY')

    ACADEMIC_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('STUDYING', 'Studying'),
        ('COMPLETED', 'Completed'),
    )
    academic_status = models.CharField(max_length=9, choices=ACADEMIC_STATUS_CHOICES, default='STUDYING')

    QUALIFICATION_CHOICES = (
        ('PRIMARY SCHOOL', 'Primary school'),
        ('MIDDLE SCHOOL', 'Middle school'),
        ('HIGH SCHOOL', 'High school'),
        ('COLLEGE', 'College'),
        ('RATHER NOT SAY', 'Rather not say'),
    )
    academic_qualification = models.CharField(max_length=14, choices=QUALIFICATION_CHOICES, default="RATHER NOT SAY")

    academic_institute_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    country = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

    objects = CustomAccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['email']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

**views.py:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .forms import SignupForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

def hello(request):
    return render(request, 'users/hello.html')

class UserRegisterView(CreateView):
    form_class = SignupForm
    template_name = "registration/register.html"

    success_url = reverse_lazy("login")
```

**forms.py:**

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_user_model()
        fields = ("username", "email", 'password1', 'password2')
```

**settings.py**

```
from pathlib import Path
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = 'My Secret key here'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'users',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'LPD_cis.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'LPD_cis.wsgi.application'

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.UserModel'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "hello"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "hello"

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

**Project urls.py:**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('users.urls')),
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
]
```

**app urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import hello, UserRegisterView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', hello, name="hello"),
    path('register/', UserRegisterView.as_view(), name="register"),

]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: You might describe a login problem, why do you assert that you're encountering a registration problem if you see your user in the admin panel ?

Comment: The problem is that, in the registration page it doesn't show any errors and shows like the registration is over. But When I try to login with the new user that I registered, I recieve the error that "Please enter a correct username and password. Note that both fields may be case-sensitive.". But I know that I've given the correct username and password. That's the reason behind me thinking that problem should be in registration side. Hope you understand whatever I did tell. If you need more clarity on the question, you may ask me right away.